# Align View to Current Transform Orientation

Tags: 3d-view, transform-orientation

Is there a keystroke or command to view along an axis of the current transform orientation (similar to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad</kbd> to view along an object's axis)? Assume there aren't any objects already aligned with the transform orientation.

The best way I've found is to create a dummy object (like an empty), use "Align to Transform Orientation", and then use the old <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad</kbd> keys. It's workable, but it's kind of tedious.

Comment: I don't think you understand. Or maybe I don't understand. There is no object aligned with the orientation. I've just created the transform orientation (specifically in Python, although there are other ways this could be useful).

Comment: Ah Ok something like setting in view3d context `context.space_data.region_3d.view_matrix = context.scene.orientations["blah"].matrix.to_4x4()`  and orthogonal rotations of.

Comment: ... btw above will prob give wrong scale, would need only set rotation part of view matrix from orientation matrix.

Comment: @batFINGER, it looks like your snippet works, except that I think you have to invert the matrix.  I'll do a little more testing and post an answer with a code example.

Answer (score 1):

Test script to put all 3d view areas in context screen into same orientation as first custom scene orientation

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix
context = bpy.context
# put all view_3d areas in screen into screen.orientation[0]
scene = context.scene
screen = context.screen
for o in scene.transform_orientation_slots:
    if o.custom_orientation:
        orientation = o.custom_orientation

print("Using ", orientation.name)
view_rot = orientation.matrix.to_quaternion()

view3dareas = [a for a in screen.areas if a.type == 'VIEW_3D']
for a in view3dareas:
    r3d = a.spaces.active.region_3d
    r3d.view_rotation = view_rot
```

To make it change from camera perspective would need something like

```
    if r3d.view_perspective == 'CAMERA':
        r3d.view_perspective = 'PERSP'
```

To look "from above" from this orientation

```
rot = Matrix.Rotation(radians(-90), 3, 'X')
#view_rot = (rot * orientation.matrix).to_quaternion()
view_rot.rotate(rot)
```