# What's the best practice to modify view port 3D camera.via bpy

Tags: python, 3d-view

I want to be able to change the current view port camera angle, as well as change to orthographic view mode. I couldn't find anything in the blender docs, so after searching it on the internet I found [this stack overflow post from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028398/change-viewport-angle-in-blender-using-python)

Though it appears to solve the problem, it's draw back is that it's almost a decade old. I was wondering if in that time, any changes have been made to bpy that allow better control over the viewport camera?

Specifically, like it's mentioned in the question I linked, I'd like to set the view port camera to the presets you get from typing the num keys, and I'd also like to switch between perspective and orthographic modes.

Comment: In what way you would like to control the viewport camera?

Comment: I updated the question to reflect this.@brockmann

Comment: Easy, you can call `bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis()` operator, see: [Set orthographic view using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149835/set-orthographic-view-using-python/149838#149838). If you'd like to switch between between 'ortho' and 'persp' just replace the operator with `bpy.ops.view3d.view_persportho(override)`... Re your Q (just trying to help): Please always try to ask a specific question here and ideally along with some code (showing some effort is part of the game), makes your question useful to future visitors too: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181110/what-is-the-python-command-to-check-if-current-view-is-in-orthographic-or-perspe  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91894/align-view-to-current-transform-orientation   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/access-view-orientation-from-python

Comment: Thanks @brockmann it worked! :D
As for adding my code, none of it really worked, so I didn't think it'd be useful to the question...

Comment: No problem @ORAS. If you need more, follow the links batFINGER posted, especially: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/access-view-orientation-from-python